WPF - Same property setting from CustomControl's generic xaml and In place where it used not overriding
Screenshots:


I have a custom control with Style as
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:IconCustom}">      
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:IconCustom}">
           <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"                             BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"                             BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
             <Border.Style>
               <Style TargetType="Border">
                 <Style.Triggers>
                   <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red">
                   </Trigger>
                 </Style.Triggers>
               </Style>
             </Border.Style>
             <TextBlock Text="Abcde"/>
           </Border>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style> 

the custom control is place in CustomTest
<uc:IconCustom Width="400" Height="400" Style="{StaticResource IconButtonStyle}"/> 

with a Style
<Style TargetType="{x:Type uc:IconCustom}" x:Key="IconButtonStyle">
   <Style.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
       </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style> 

here Yellow is not overriding on Red for MouseOver, why this happens, How to fix?
Tried setting Default style for MouseOver, and Style from CustomTest, it also not worked, I want if no style is given in CustomTest, then Default style (Red) will take, otherwise if Style applied in CustomTest, then Yellow will take,
